# how to use input from one component in app.js

Tags: react-native

Hello im trying to create a todo list in react native and i have an addtask component that is used for the input and the add button i want to use the input from the add task component to create a new task with the data on app.js. so how can i pass the input data after i click on the plus button to the app component. even just to print it as a text on the screen, i just dont understand how to pass it

app.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Task from './components/Task';
import AddTask from './components/AddTask';





export default function App() {

  const [todos, setTodos]= useState([
    {text:'hello', key:'1'},
  ]);
  


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.taskWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Today's Tasks</Text>
      </View>

        <View style={styles.tasks}>
          <Task />
        
          <Task text={''} />
          <Task text={''} />
      </View>


      <View style={styles.addTask}>
        <AddTask />
      </View>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E8EAED',
  },
  taskWrapper: {
    paddingTop: 80,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  tasks: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  addTask: {
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
});
```

addtask.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text,Keyboard, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity,TouchableWithoutFeedback, } from 'react-native';
import KeyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Task from './Task';



const AddTask = () => {
    const [task, setTask] = useState('');
    const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);
    
    const handleAddTask = () => {
        setTaskItems([...taskItems, task]);
        setTask('');
        console.log(taskItems);
        return(
            taskItems
        );
      };
    


  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} value = {task} onChangeText={text => setTask(text)} placeholder={'Write a task'} />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(task)}>
        <View style={styles.plusButton}>
          <Text style={styles.plus}>+</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  input: {
    height: 60,
    borderWidth: 1,
    
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: 'white',
  },
  plusButton: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 15,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: 'white',
  },
  plus: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#E8EAED',
  },
  Task:{
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: 20,
        marginTop:10,
        marginHorizontal:20,
        borderRadius:10,
        flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        marginBottom:20,
    },

});

export default AddTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to understand as a question, but I think you're asking how to add a task to a list of tasks.

It looks like you're rendering 3 tasks in the app.js file, within the View with the style attribute set to {styles.tasks}

I think instead, you want to render the tasks that are within the todos state.

This can be accomplished by writing

```
    {todos.map((todo) => (
        <Text>{todo.text}</Text>
      ))}
```

In order to get the text you're writing in the input within the AddTask component, you need to be able to add the task to the top level components state, `todos`

This could be accomplished by writing some code in the top level component to add to that task, e.g.

```
const handleAddTask = (task) => {
    setTodos([...todos, task]);
  }
```

and passing it down to the bottom level component.

You can accomplish this by expecting it in the bottom level component

```
const AddTask = ({handleAddTask}) => {

})
```

and passing it in the top level task.

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.taskWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Today's Tasks</Text>
      </View>

      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <Text>{todo.text}</Text>
      ))}

      <View style={styles.tasks}>
        <Task />

        <Task text={""} />
        <Task text={""} />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.addTask}>
        <AddTask handleAddTask={handleAddTask} />
      </View>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
```

Now, when you use the button onPress handler, have that callback function run handleAddTask with the inputs value.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(task)}>
        <View style={styles.plusButton}>
          <Text onPress={() => handleAddTask(task} style={styles.plus}>+</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: it does add a new task but without the content